# UIImage fill colour but not border

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the stars image as shown and I'd like to fill the colour based on rating of a user.

[image: five stars]

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

a) use the flood algorithm to fill an area (all connected pixels with the same color) starting from a given pixel with one color.
For that you'd have to fix the image though as the white in the stars 1 and 2 connect directly.

b) setup a NSBezierPath for a star and fill the path. Transform it to move the path horizontally from star to star.
You should also fix the image so that the stars are evenly distributed.

c) use 5 pngs and based on the number of stars to coulor, draw a different png.
This sean image of an empty star & an image of ONE fullstarems easiest.

---

best IMHO:

d) have 3 images. ONE empty star, ONE full star, ONE half star, draw the image 5 times .. depending on how many stars are full, half full or empty

Comment: but for b), Is there even a way to fill UIBezierPath half or a quarter?

Comment: you would have a path for ONE star only and then reuse it Five times by simply moving along the x axis (you'd just transform it to match!)

Comment: yup, but I'll need half star. for example for 3.5 rating, I'll show 3 and half stars coloured and the rest to be white.